# Application registration in service StillImage

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2010

Application registration in service StillImage

Operating system – Windows XP SP3
Programming environment – Delphi 2010

I made the interface module:

```
unit StillImage;

interface

uses
  Windows;


const
  STI_VERSION = $00000002;

type
  IStillImageW = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{641BD880-2DC8-11D0-90EA-00AA0060F86C}']
    .......
      function RegisterLaunchApplication(AppName, CommandLine: LPWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    .......
  end;

  PIStillImageW = ^IStillImageW;


function StiCreateInstanceW(hinst: HINST; dwVer: DWORD; ppSti: PIStillImageW; punkOuter: IUnknown): HResult; stdcall; external 'sti.dll' name 'StiCreateInstanceW';

implementation
end.
```

I try to call a method StiCreateInstanceW:

```
var
  Still_Image: IStillImageW;
  H_Res: HResult;
  pwszAppName: PWideChar;
  pwszCommandLine: PWideChar;
  wszAppName: array[0..1000] of WideChar;
  wszCommandLine: array[0..1000] of WideChar;
  ........

begin
  ........
  H_Res := StiCreateInstanceW(GetModuleHandle(nil), STI_VERSION, @Still_Image, nil);
  if H_Res <> S_OK then raise ...............


  FillChar(wszAppName, SizeOf(wszAppName), 0);
  FillChar(wszCommandLine, SizeOf(wszCommandLine), 0);

  pwszAppName     := StringToWideChar('Calculator', @wszAppName, SizeOf(wszAppName)-1);
  pwszCommandLine := StringToWideChar('c:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe', @wszCommandLine, SizeOf(wszCommandLine)-1);

  H_Res := 0;
  H_Res := Still_Image.RegisterLaunchApplication(pwszAppName, pwszCommandLine);
  if H_Res <> S_OK then raise ...............
  ...............
  ...............
```

As a result I get:

```
H_Res = 0x80070057
```

This means: `E_INVALIDARG` (One or more arguments are invalid)

or: `STIERR_INVALID_PARAM`

I did everything exactly as written here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I've tried the following lines:

```
'c:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe'
'"c:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe"'
'\"c:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe\"'
'c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe'
'\"c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe\"'
```

No difference.

Always an error - `E_INVALIDARG` / `STIERR_INVALID_PARAM`

Comment: Not the problem, but your call to `StringToWideChar` passes byte size and it should pass character length. All that code is pointless though. Write `RegisterLaunchApplication('blah', 'blah')`, or if you have the strings in variables, write `RegisterLaunchApplication(PChar(str1), PChar(str2))`